# Asp.net Core Multiple File Upload to Database

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

How can I write multiple files into database ,with this code I'm uploading multiple files to upload folder ,but how to create multiple rows in database for every file thanks!

```
    public IActionResult Create(Photos photos)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var date = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(4);
            var photoAddDate = photos.PhotoAddedData = date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd','HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

            if (photos.formFiles != null && photos.formFiles.Count > 0)
            {
                string folderName = "Upload";
                string webRootPath = _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath;
                string newPath = Path.Combine(webRootPath, folderName);
                if (!Directory.Exists(newPath))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(newPath);
                }
                foreach (IFormFile item in photos.formFiles)
                {
                    if (item.Length > 0)
                    {
                        string fileName = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(item.ContentDisposition).FileName.Trim('"');
                        string fullPath = Path.Combine(newPath, fileName);
                        photos.PhotoPath += "/" + Path.GetFileName(item.FileName);
                        using (var stream = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Create))
                        {
                            item.CopyTo(stream);
                        }
                    }
                }
                _context.Add(photos);
                _context.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }


        }
        ViewData["NewsId"] = new SelectList(_context.News, "NewsId", "NewsName", photos.NewsId);
        return View(photos);
    }
```

in model class :

```
    [NotMapped]
    [Required]
    public List<IFormFile> formFiles { get; set; }
```

Comment: Create a SQL database, create a column of VARBINARY and store the `byte[]` there. Or store the `byte[]` into Azure Blob storage.  You get the byte[] by goind a File.Open.Read and the result stream reader gives you the bytes. There are a ton of examples. Please search a bit more. Dont know what IFromFile is but you need to store things in database using a byte[] prmitive

Comment: thanks for help ,byte[] won't give me multiple rows in database ,i need one per file ,now it looks like this ,it writes both file pathes inside one row  /Interior10-min.jpg/Railing6-min.jpg

Answer (score 0):

inside your for loop, you need to use the syntax below

```
byte[] myFile = stream.ToByteArray();
var myFileClass = new myFileClass{
    MyFile = myFile
};
_dbContext.MyFileTable.Add(myFileClass);
```